# filtering dataframes by datetimeindex- last business day of each month

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a df with which can be represented below with a date column and 4 variable columns.

```
Date          A B C D
2015-10-31    6 7 3 7
2015-11-01    1 3 9 4
2015-11-02    4 5 8 1
2015-11-03    4 2 5 9
```

I am looking to filter the df on the last business day of each month by adding an additional column called 'EndofMonth' and taking the trailing nth row from each month:

```
df['EndOfMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(1)
df.apply(lambda x: x.sort('dt', ascending=True).tail(1))
```

This is giving me an error. Any ideas on how to better solve this?

Comment: what's `MonthEnd(1)`?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.resample('M', on='Date').apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=2)
```

[image]

---

***response to comment***

```
d1 = df.resample('M').apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=2)
d1.index = d1.index.droplevel(0)
d1
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error on this- TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'. Maybe because it is reading my Data col. not as a datetime? @piRSquared

Comment: `on` is a new parameter for `resample` in pandas 0.19.  you can do `df.set_index('Date').resample('M').apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=2)`

Comment: @piRSquared- i am sorry for the continued questions but- this created a multi-index (2 dates). I would ideally like to get rid of one of the index columns. How can i do this? I know how to delete a column (df.drop) but i am not sure how to drop the index.